# Reset Aquamacs colours

Tags: colors, aquamacs

I'm not quite sure how, but when I start Aquamacs now, the background is black with a yellow cursor and white text. Being a beginner to Aquamacs, its hard for me to tell what's gone wrong.

[image]

Above is a screenshot of what my setup looks like.
Any help in return Aquamacs to its original colour scheme would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient way to choose color scheme is an interactive one:

**M-x color-theme-select**

Pick the color theme that you want to use.

In order to keep this choice between emacs restarts:

Menu → Options → Appearance → Auto Face Mode → Use Current Style for Text Mode
Menu → Options → Appearance → Adopt Current Fram Parameters
Say yes to the dialog.

( taken from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsFAQ#toc20 )

Answer (score 0):

[Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org) has a link to the support mailing list.  There are many helpful people who can help you out, provided you've tried looking it up in the manual/FAQ/Google beforehand.

Comment: The point of this site is to get answers here, not to direct people to other sites. Could you please edit your answer with a possible solution?